# Let Q(√2) = (a + b√2 | a, b ∈ Q), prove that Q(√2) is a number field

Tags: linear-algebra

Let Q(√2) = (a + b√2 | a, b ∈ Q), prove that Q(√2) is a number field. I have no idea how to prove this. Someone can give a prove process?

Comment: Define arithmetic operations $+$, $\cdot$ and verify the field axioms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove all of the field axioms :

1. $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{K}$: $ x+y = y+x$
2. $\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{K}$: $(x+y)+z = x+(y+z)$
3. $\exists 0 \in \mathbb{K} / \forall x \in \mathbb{K}$: $x+0=x$
4. $\forall x \in \mathbb{K}$ $ \exists y \in \mathbb{K} / x+y=0$
5. $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{K}$: $x\cdot y = y\cdot x$
6. $\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{K}$: $(x\cdot y)\cdot z = x\cdot (y\cdot z)$
7. $\exists 1\in \mathbb{K} / \forall x \in \mathbb{K}$: $x\cdot 1 = x$
8. $\forall x \in \mathbb{K} x \neq 0$ $ \exists y \in \mathbb{K} / x\cdot y = 1$
9. $\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{K} x\dot (y+z) = x\cdot y + x\cdot z$

For example, lets prove 4:

Let $a+b\sqrt{2} \in Q({\sqrt{2}})$.

As $a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \implies -a,-b \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $-a-b\sqrt{2} \in Q(\sqrt{2})$.

Then you have that $a+b\sqrt{2} + (-a-b\sqrt{2}) = 0$.

Then, $\forall x \in Q(\sqrt{2})$ $ \exists y \in Q(\sqrt{2})$ s.t $x+y=0$.

Notice that we used that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field and verifies 4. to prove this.